# How to find the relative difference between two quaternions?

Tags: rotation, difference, quaternions

[Cube Rotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aujFy.png)

I am trying to find the relative rotation between two quaternions such that both difference quaternions will be the same for A1 to B1 and A2 to B2.

Cube B is rotated 90 degrees around its z axis in both examples.

I use this equation to find the difference:
`Quaternion q = B * Inverse(A)`
The outputs of these are displayed in the diagram.
They are not the same.

The arrows represent the local orientation of the cubes.

My understanding of quaternions is obviously limited.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another post.
I realised it was the same problem.

I need to reverse the order of multiplications to get the rotation in the correct frame of reference.

```
Quaternion q = Inverse(A) * B;
```

[How do you rotate 2 quaternions back to starting position and then calculate the relative rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149231/how-do-you-rotate-2-quaternions-back-to-starting-position-and-then-calculate-the?rq=1)